# Heat Maps only for feature layer (why not for dynamic layer ?) in ArcGIS Java script API 3.0/3.2

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, heat-map

I am referring this link to generate the heat map. In [this](http://tmappsevents.esri.com/website/heatmap/index.html) example they used feature layer and I tried using dynamic layer but getting an error (that no map is displaying).

I researched on Google regarding this but not able to find such information .

So is there any specific requirement/purpose to use feature layer instead of dynamic layer??

If anyone know this please let me know….

Thanks…

Software platform : ArcGIS 10.1 (Server & Desktop), ArcGIS JSAPI 3.0/3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an ArcGISDynamicLayer, but you instantiate as a feature layer. Not sure what mode you would use...MODE_SNAPSHOT, MODE_ONDEMAND

```
 //Create a feature layer for map
featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://yourserver/arcgis/rest/services/folder/servicename/MapServer/0", {
    mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["STN_CASGEM_STATION_ID", "WLM_GROUND_SURFACE_ELEVATION"], //all would be ["*"]
});
```

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jshelp/#inside_feature_layers

> Feature layers can be created by referencing a layer from either a map
>   service or a feature service or by specifying a feature colleciton
>   object.
>
> - Use a map service if you just want to retrieve geometries and    attributes from the server and symbolize them yourself. (In the final 
>     release, the map service will be able to return its symbols.)
> - Use a feature service if you want to take advantage of symbols from    the service's source map document. Also use a feature service if you
>     plan on doing editing with the feature layer. Feature layers honor
>     any feature templates configured in the source map document.
> - Feature collection objects are used to create a feature layer based    on the supplied definition.

Comment: thanks for the reply..nice explanation..the reason to use dynamic layer is that it takes less time to display 800 points on the map..If I convert as feature layer then it takes little bit extra time for rendering and getting warning in the console.. I will soon put the code on JS fiddle.

Comment: I have changed mode that is mode_selection still its not working and debugging the code..I will post the code may be today evening or tomorrow morning.. thanks once again : )